# How to check Treeview collapse/expand icon clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in mouse_down event.

```
private void treeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

Now, In mouse_down event How to check user clicked expand/collpase icon not node?

Note : Before_Expand and Before_Check events will not work bcoz mouse_down event fire first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void treeView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var Test = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (Test.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.PlusMinus)
    { 
       //You can check here
    }
}
```